# angularjs,bootstrap multiselect with one click, without using ctrl key

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

Is this achievable ?
I have the following form

```
   <select multiple class="form-control">
                <option
                        ng-model="selectedCountry.selectedLocations"
                        ng-repeat="location in selectedCountry.locations"
                        ng-click="locationsSelection(location)"
                        ng-selected="selectedCountry.selectedLocations.indexOf(location)!=-1">{{loc}}
                </option>

   </select>
```

What the code does it give me a list of countries, by pressing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key I can do multiselct but I wanna be able to do this with one click and don't know how to do it.
I used the ng-selected directives, but it highlights multiple places only if I load back (if I press on another list and go back to the country list, it will load and highlight all the previously clicked countries)
I have a scope that holds all the countries that have been clicked but I'm not being able to highlight multiple countries from the list without pressing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

PS:

I have created an example of what I have.

http://plnkr.co/edit/We3k6Pc93RKHicmhsJVu?p=preview

I want my listbox to look like the one in the example. At the moment I can multiselect but I need to use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. I want to be able to click once on a location and have a selected and if I click again it deselects without the need to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

I hope my example is clear now.
Thank you

Comment: I think a lot of problem in bootstrap multiselect, I have generated a multiselect, if you found any mistake from here, please inform me. see http://plnkr.co/edit/84UP9B29HkAINNgNELRR?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Shohel, the multiselect you've provide is different.
I want like mine which is similar to a list and not a dropdown but with functions similar to yours

Comment: Ok no problem, you just out checkbox and his fuctionality from template